# Complexity of LCM

Tags: time-complexity

What is the complexity of code to find LCM. This complexity will never be O(n). Also the steps would vary according to input. Thanks.

```
public static int findGCD (int a, int b) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = a % b;
        if (c > 0) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
    } while (c != 0);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Even though it is completely algorithmic question try adding language tags with questions. In your case I guess it is C++.

Comment: This is solving for the GCD as @Zel said and the complexity for the algorithm is O (log N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a = 100 and b be any value less than 100.
In worst case what is maximum value of a % b ? Its 49, only if b = 51.
This means even in worst case, on each iteration the value of a is halved!

> So this is O(LOGN) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try google. You are using Eucledian algorithm for GCD. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency) is wikipedia article for algorithmic efficieny for this.